# Why is my local storage item disappearing when I try listing them on my page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

I have a search bar for a weather dashboard that saves searches in local storage. I'm able to use getItem to get the last searched city to display on my page, but it disappears after a new city is searched. I'm trying to get all searched cities to list and be able to click them to pull the information for that city again. How can I get my getItem's to stay on the page together?

```
 localStorage.setItem(cityName, JSON.stringify(data));

var history = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem(cityName));
        var historyList = document.getElementById('pastCities');

        function searchHistory(text) {
            document.getElementById('pastCities').innerHTML =
              `
                <button style="padding:10px; font-weight:bold; text-transform: uppercase; background-color:#4267cea6; width:100px; text-align:center">${cityName} </button>
              `
              
            for (i = 0; i < history.length; i++) {
                $(".pastCities").children('textarea').val(localStorage.getItem(history[i]));
                
           }
        }
        console.log(history);
        searchHistory();
     })
```

I tried using a for loop to keep them in an array, and I tried using an if statement to keep them on the page unless cleared.

Comment: this line `localStorage.setItem(cityName, JSON.stringify(data));` when is that run? what is value of `cityName`? what is the value of `history`? do you have items in localStorage named all the values in `history`?

Comment: isn't that suppose to be `localStorage.setItem('history', JSON.stringify([cityName, ...lastHistory]) )` ?

Comment: cityName = document.getElementById('search').value;   It is run in my click event function. My setItem works just fine. It holds the name of the city I search and the weather data that goes along with that city. So that feature has no issue. I'm trying to then pull that info with getItem to show on my page.